# Trying to re-project a folder of shapefiles using Python Script

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

I am trying to reproject multiple shapefiles in a folder. When I run my program this is the error I am getting:

line 8221, in Project
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000670: output Output Dataset or Feature Class is same as input Input Dataset or Feature Class
Failed to execute (Project).

I checked my code and I'm not seeing what Im doing wrong. What could be the issue here?

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\users\\data\\shapefile_roads"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outWorkspace = "C:\\users\\data\\shapefile_roads"

for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        # Determine if the input has a defined coordinate system, can't project it if it does not
    dsc = arcpy.Describe(infc)

    if dsc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
        print ('skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: ' + infc)
    else:
        # Determine the new output feature class path and name
        outfc = os.path.join(outWorkspace, infc)

        # Set output coordinate system
        outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference('WGS 1984')

        # run project tool
        arcpy.Project_management(infc, outfc, outCS)

        # check messages
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your output dataset has the same name as your input dataset. Try setting a different workspace for the output, like:
`outWorkspace = "C:\\users\\data\\shapefile_roads_projected"`

Comment: Ahhh of course. That did the trick!

Comment: What is "overwriteOutput = True" doing then? I have multiple batch copy/convert for loops that I'd like to not to have to make a new output folder for, for each step of the way. I have no need for the intermediate files.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the error message is pretty straight forward:

> ERROR 000670: output Output Dataset or Feature Class is same as input
>   Input Dataset or Feature Class Failed to execute (Project).

The `infc` and `outfc` variables both point to the same feature class.

One easy fix would be to output into a different folder.

So, create a new folder called "projected" within the "shapefile_roads" folder, and change outWorkspace to:

```
outWorkspace = "C:\\users\\data\\shapefile_roads\\projected"
```